# How can I reinstall the boot loader?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, grub2, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I've just installed windows 7, and I can't access Ubuntu any more.
Is there any way I can install the boot loader without reinstalling Ubuntu all over again ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Insert your Ubuntu live (desktop) CD or flash drive, reboot your computer from CD/Flash drive into a live, desktop session.

Install and run Boot-Repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
gksu boot-repair
```

Click "Recommended repair" -> apply.

For other options, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: You are most welcome.