# recovering linux boot loader after reinstalling windows

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

i have a notebook in which i installed windows, and then linux on another partition.
Today, i had to reinstall windows and now i don't have access to the boot menu when the computer boots.
Now i can't seem to get the grub boot menu, so i can't access my linux system.

I have tried to follow these instructions from the Ubuntu Documentation, but i can't seem to get it.

I ran the Ubuntu Live CD and
1 - I can't find Boot-Repair
2 - in the terminal, when i run fdisk -l, i get:

```
/dev/sda1 - HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda2 - HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda3 - Extended  
/dev/sda5 - HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda6 - HPFS/NTFS/exFAT  
/dev/sda7 - Linux swap / Solaris
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Please follow this [link](http://askubuntu.com/q/139121/37006)

Comment: I can't see the linux partition in the list - do you remember which partition it was? It lookls like Windows install just wiped the linux partition, so reinstalling GRUB is not really your first priority now...

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18566/how-do-i-restore-grub-after-windows-has-deleted-it

Comment: yes, Sergei, i think you may be right. i really f**d up this time

Answer (score 2):

Find? I thought that you had to use the live cd and then install boot-repair, as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86298/how-can-i-reinstall-the-boot-loader). Is that what you did?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134794/how-can-i-boot-into-ubuntu-after-repairing-windows-7) is also relevant.

Hope that helps!

Did you perhaps had an image of your windows system in a hidden partition and recovered it from there? If that's the case, then you probably lost your ubuntu partition. Just saying cause I had the same problem and the only thing I could do is install everything from the start.